# Exporting SSRS report to excel with freezing panel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I created a report in SSRS and now I need to export it to Excel with the table header 
freezed. How can I achieve this?

I have googled on this topic. I know the content in page header can be freezed in Excel. But how can I put the table header only in page header? More worse, I even cannot add a new table at page header.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I find out that it is not possible to make the table header freezed. But for a workaround, I use the text boxes to simulate the table header in the page header. It is obviously not a good way.

Answer (score -2):

In your Table Properties, you can set Row Headers and/or Column Headers to be rendered on every page or set them to remain visible while scrolling ("freeze" them).

Comment: Are you sure this will work when I export the report to Excel?